# Copy variable Range (based off cell value) to another tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm struggling to set variable range to be copied into another tab in the same sheet.
Fixed table range is defined as "Sprzedaż template!B84:Z95". Actually I would like to have that range going from B84 to Z84, when Z84 adds incremental number based off P16 cell value in a sheet (that changes). So for example P16 = 5, then range would be B84:Z88, if P16=12, then range would be B84:Z95 and so on. How do I do that?

Below is script with fixed range value:

```
function Import(){
  importRange(
    "1GQtw8xjebZHSgNKvIYvGEal0V0UT4456854X6XTQA4ybQWfqc", //source ID
    "template!B84:Z95", //sourceRange
    "1GQtw8xjebZHSgNKvIYvGffdsaEal0V0UTyX6XTQA4ybQWfqc",//destinationID
    "DataBase!B2"//destinationRangeStart
    );
};

function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart){

  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByID(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByID(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getRow(), // Start row
    destStartRange.getColumn(), // Start column
    sourceVals.lenght, // Row lenght 
    sourceVals[0].lenght // Col width
    );


    destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: It is unclear why you would want to do that with a script when a simple spreadsheet formula would seem to suffice. Please clarify.

Comment: Tab I want to copy range is template that user needs to fill. Once filled entries will be transferred to another tab which forms type of data base. Hope it clarifies

Comment: Hi doubleunary, would you able to help me further to understand what I'm doing wrong? I've answered to my own question with revised code but unfortunately is not working.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Answer (score 1):

To do that with a script, use `Range.offset()`, like this:

```
  const sourceSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const numRows = sourceSs.getRange('template!P16').getValue();
  const sourceRange = sourceSs.getRange('template!B84:Z84')
    .offset(0, 0, numRows);
  const targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByID('...');
  const targetRange = targetSs.getRange('Database!B2:Z2')
    .offset(0, 0, numRows);
  targetRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues());
```

If you are doing this within one spreadsheet file, you can do the same with a spreadsheet formula, without requiring a script. Use `offset()` in cell `Database!B2`, like this:

`=offset(template!B84:Z84, 0, 0, P16)`